# Transparent background of Vim editor within the xfce-4 terminal

Tags: vim, xfce, vimrc, transparency

Is there a way to have a transparent Vim session within the xfce-4 terminal?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I made mine transparent in gnome-terminal (and I'm guessing this will work for xfce-4 too)

I'm using [Molokai theme](https://github.com/mrtazz/molokai.vim/blob/master/colors/molokai.vim) (the 256 colour version).

I just had to change one line.

(original):

```
hi Normal          ctermfg=252 ctermbg=233
```

(my version, with transparent background):

```
hi Normal          ctermfg=252 ctermbg=none
```

Comment: Juanjo's answer is great, and inspired me to add this edit: `hi NonText ctermfg=250 ctermbg=none` This ensures that the parts of buffers that don't have content, are transparent.

Comment: Note that you can just add this line to your `.vimrc` and it will have the same effect: `hi Normal guibg=NONE ctermbg=NONE`. And it won't change the forgroud color for the `Normal` group either.

Answer (score 2):

In the Terminal Preferences dialog, the Appearance tab has a "Transparent background" option to make the window transparent. If you found this option and set it appropriately, I can think of two reasons that it might not be working for you:

1) You might be using gvim instead of console vim within the terminal. If Vim opens up a new window, then you're using gvim instead of console vim.

2) You might have a vim colorscheme that explicitly sets white or black as the background color. It's unusual to have a misbehaving color scheme like this, so I don't think it's likely.

I think it's most likely that you're actually using gvim instead of console vim.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've figured it out: the vim coloscheme had ctermbg set to "black", I've removed it and now the background is transparent. I'm definitely using vim.

Comment: So my answer was right, then, wasn't it? I suggested it might be a colorscheme that explicitly sets the background to black or white, which indeed turned out to be the problem.

Comment: sorry for accepting your answer so late.. it missed my attention somehow..